# How to bundle local typescript files into main bundle using Rollup

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, rollup

I am trying to create an npm module that can be used in the browser.

I'm using typescript and rollup.

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "strict": true,
    "rootDir": "src"
  }
}
```

and my `rollup.config.js` is:

```js
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: {
    dir: "lib",
    format: "iife",
  },
  plugins: [typescript()],
};
```

Inside `src/index.ts` I have the following:

```js
// src/index.ts
import log from './log'

const myFn = () => {
 ...myFn code
}
```

My issue is that in the bundle, I get the following:

```
// lib/index.js bundle
var log_1 = require("./log");
```

When I actually want to bundle the `log` file inside the main `lib/index.js`.

How can I do this with Typescript and rollup?

Note: I have tried to add `outFile` ([ts docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outFile)) but that is not supported by "@rollup/plugin-typescript".

Do I have to do the tsc compile myself and then the rollup bundle?

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to this but if anyone comes across this question, I actually moved to Webpack, and it was much simpler.

Comment: having a similar issue here it seems :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71796571/how-to-replace-global-variable-with-relative-import-using-rollup No option for webpack unfortunately

Answer (score 7):

Rollup requires the TypeScript compiler to generate ES Modules in order to properly bundle your code. You'll need to change the module format to "ESNext" instead of "CommonJS" in your `tsconfig.json` or change the `@rollup/plugin-typescript` configuration in your Rollup config:

```
typescript({ module: "ESNext" })
```

As of [rollup/plugins#788](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/pull/788), you will get a warning if this is not configured correctly.

> @rollup/plugin-typescript: Rollup requires that TypeScript produces ES Modules. Unfortunately your configuration specifies a "module" other than "esnext". Unless you know what you're doing, please change "module" to "esnext" in the target tsconfig.json file or plugin options.

Comment: I had the same error, but still rollup complains for not JS files after fixing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71796571/how-to-replace-global-variable-with-relative-import-using-rollup if someone has any insight please

Comment: For me it still produces a warning: `Plugin typescript: @rollup/plugin-typescript: Rollup requires that TypeScript produces ES Modules. Unfortunately your configuration specifies a "module" other than "esnext". Unless you know what you're doing, please change "module" to "esnext" in the target tsconfig.json file or plugin options.`
And this is despite putting override for `module` in plugin options: even tried wraping in `compilerOptions`, no dice. Warning is gone once I change `module` in `tsconfig.json`.