# How to replace global variable with relative import using Rollup?

Tags: javascript, typescript, window, rollup

Is it possible to use a global variable with rollup to result to a relative import of a file in the bundled dest?
Something like

`const file = window.MY_GLOBAL;`

to

`` const file = import(`path-to-file-in-dest`); ``

I've seen the [`define` plugin](https://github.com/sastan/rollup-plugin-define)

```js
define({
   replacements: {
      "window.MY_GLOBAL": `import ("${(path_to_file_in_dest`)}")`,
    },
}),
```

but get `Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:12)`

### Updated:

Trying also with the `replace` plugin:

```
// rollup.config.js
const externalFile = path.resolve("./myJsonFile.json");
plugins: [
 typescript(),
 json(),
 resolve(),
 commonjs(),
 replace({
            MY_JSON_FILE: externalFile,
            preventAssignment: true,
        }),
...],

//myCode.ts
export const MY_JSON_FILE = "";

import(MY_JSON_FILE)
 .then((data) => {
      window.X = data;
      console.debug(window.X);
 })
 .catch((error) => {
      console.error(`Unable to find file`,error);
      return;
 });
```

but still getting error when `rollup -c`

```
(!) Plugin typescript: @rollup/plugin-typescript: Rollup requires that TypeScript produces ES Modules. Unfortunately your configuration specifies a "module" other than "esnext". Unless you know what you're doing, please change "module" to "esnext" in the target tsconfig.json file or plugin options.
```

and when I change the "module" to 'ESNext' as it prompts me to do...

```
    typescript({ module: "ESNext" }),
```

it complains for:

```
 Error: Duplicate regular expression flag (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
src/myCode.ts (512:0)
512:             import(MY_JSON_FILE)
```

Comment: What is the line of code your browser is running when it throws the error "Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:12)"?

Comment: @Matthias found the case for that one but define plugin cannot work - please see updated :)